# How can I close rice bag?

Tags: kitchen

Consider the following rice bag

[image]

I want to close the rice bag mouth so that insects and other unnecessary materials will not fall into the rice.

I have plenty of rice bags like this in my home. I keep them in the hall to ensure that no unnecessary materials will fall into them. Now I want to move them to the kitchen again and hence want to know the best method to close them. There is no zip to close them and I cannot twist them (daily) because the bag will have full of rice.

How can I close the rice bag?

Comment: Clarify the quantity of rice *per bag* (typical size).  How many bags are open by now?

Comment: I put mine in a food safe 5 gallon Bucket to protect it from insects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the bag is not given but from the rope handle must be quite sizeable.

If you cannot obtain a canister with a lid of sufficient size, then

- place the bag inside a polythene bag that is large enough to twist shut, or roll shut.

Answer (score 7):

Introducing the **Divide and Conquer HACK:**

When you buy in bulk quantities, redistribute some of each different food stock into a smaller container for frequent use that is easy to handle and closes securely.

An empty, previously-used package might be convenient as it's already labeled and made of appropriate material. A wide-mouth, screw-top jar would be a good candidate. Don't forget to label the container with the correct expiry (best before) date.

Remove enough from the larger, bulk, storage container so that it can be folded, twisted, or rolled closed, fastened securely, and stored in an appropriate location.

Some bulk food containers are made so that they can be resealed. For those that are not, pay careful attention to opening fresh supplies with a minimal opening and where the container can be easily resealed — a bag corner, say.

Good luck.

Comment: The picture shows a cup lying in the bag on top of the rice. Ripping open the top of the bag so that rice can be scooped out isn't a good plan. As this answer says, cut off a corner of the bag and pour out the rice when needed.

Answer (score 4):

You can try bag clips. They are fairly cheap and work well. There are some bigger sizers that can clip onto the bags if you fold the opened part vertically (like making a triangle)

If you don't want to spend money, you should try as suggested to snip off a corner of the bag and pour the rice out. Then fold the open corner and put something heavy on it.

[image]

Comment: For a small corner cut from a foil bag (as indicated in the photo, though this one was teared off a bit [too] much), after folding the area once or twice, a clothespin from the clothes line equally keeps this fix and closed.  It suffices if the content anyway is accessed multiple times a week where one may check if it is still good.

Comment: +1   Clothes pegs will do a similar job  but you don't get as good a seal

Answer (score 3):

It is nothing wrong to transfer goods like rice, cereals, or flour from a larger bag into wide mouth [mason jar's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mason_jar):

[image]

(credit: *loc. cit*)

They come in different shapes (cylindrical; though on occasion in square cross section, too) and storage volume (like 1L, 1.5L, 2L; or a half of a gallon).  It is easy to open and close them, and to keep track how much they store (easier than with bags, in my experience) and they keep the storage in good shape.

Comment: I personally reuse the huge Whey protein containers. They have wide opening and I even reuse the whey scoop to mesure the rice.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a vacuum sealer (I've even used a soldering iron in the past... the idea is to melt the two open sides of the container together creating an air-tight seal. Usually it just requires you to press both sides of the bag into the machine and hit "seal" (not "vacuum-seal"; they usually come with a variety of features, one of which should be just "seal" that is the one you want).

Answer (score 0):

Binder clips are my go to for closing bags, such as rice bags, chip bags and type of clamping needed to make it air tight so your items should stay fresh.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a sizeable gap between the top of the bag, where the crimped seal was and the top level of the rice. Roll down the top of the bag until you can roll no more and the secure the sealing roll with a length of two of adhesive tape.